# Python MySQL: Special escaped character leads to insert error

Tags: python, mysql

I am using parameter binding to insert into MySQL 5.7.29 via python 3.x. Somehow I am still getting an insert error while inserting `'`

```
Failed to save datasets. INSERT IGNORE INTO table (
      `name`
) 
VALUES ('L\'Test') Error  1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Test'' at line 1
```

Query:

```
self.curr.execute(""" 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table (
        `name`
    ) 
    VALUES (%s)
    
    """, (                                                           
        item['test'],                    
    )
)
```

I thought that in that case escaping is not needed?

Full query error message:

```
Failed to save datasets. INSERT IGNORE INTO manufacturers (name) VALUES ('L\'Oreal Deutschland GmbH Geschäftsbereich La Roche-Posay') Error  1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Oreal Deutschland GmbH Geschäftsbereich La Roche-Posay'' at line 1
```

SQL mode:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

> `IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

MySQL Pipeline:

```
class mysql_pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host        = 'rex',
            user        = 'crawler',
            passwd      = 'asdsadf3',
            database    = 'test',
            charset     = 'utf8'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()
        self.curb = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item, spider)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item, spider):
```

Comment: Whats the value of item, how r u initialising it

Comment: The value is: "L'Oreal" and I am initialisiing like this in scrapy:  test    = scrapy.Field()

Comment: What happens when you execute the query directly in mysql console

Comment: You might be editing and posting dummy code here. If possible please post the complete snippet, so we can run and check

Comment: Good question. it does execute with 0 datasets inserted as it is already inside the dataset. I get a Warning: #1062 duplicate data

Comment: @Sriram Added full query to question

Comment: Do `cursor._last_executed` to print the SQL that got executed which produced this error. Compare the sqls

Comment: You can try the MySQL quote function. `INSERT IGNORE INTO table (
        name
    ) 
    VALUES (QUOTE(%s))`

Comment: What version of MySQL and could have have configured ANSI requirements?

Comment: I suspect your MySQL is running with NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES in the sql_mode. That should be only way to get that error.

Comment: This is 5.7.29 and I am not aware of this Backslash_escapes command. Usually I work with PHP and there I am using mysql_real_escape_string() which works perfectly.  I tried: print(self.curr._last_executed) but got: AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed'

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I am not using this SQL-Mode. Added modes to question.

Comment: wow, my next guess would be character_set_connection is wrong somehow, but even then the \ is pretty much the same in all character sets. Can you show where you create the connection?

Comment: Added to question. This is within a scrapy framework and I added a mysql pipeline which I am calling during the crawl.

Comment: can you reproduce with just `self.curr.execute(r"SELECT 'Test\'Escape'")`?  It really looks like connector escapes but it is interpreted wrong.

Comment: This works, it returns: ("Test'Escape",). It is worth to mention, that the dataset that leads to an error has been inserted into MySQL, but on the second try (insert ignore) it will produce the mentioned error. I deleted the entry from db and run the crawler again, it inserts and then it brings up the errors for the following entries. I am using scrayp 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

From the syntax of your code, I assume that you are using MySQL Connector. You can write query like this.

```
insert_statement = (
    "INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename (columnname) "  # mind the space after (columnname) 
    "VALUES (%s)"
)
actual_data = (item['test'],) 

cursor.execute(insert_statement, actual_data)
```

It is easier to read and does exactly what you want to do.

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: I tried this out of curriosity but it looks like just a different formating for the same thing. I also added a needed trailing comma within the actual_data statement. Result is the same, but you are right it is more readable. Thank you for that. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Missed one small detail, there has to be  `,` after `item['test']` . That is becuase value of actual_data is tuple, and if tuple has only one element,  `,` is required after that element.

Comment: That is true but it does not fix the problem

Comment: What happens if you use double quotes in `item["test"]`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement shown in error and the error code, your sql_mode must include NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES. After creating your connection, you can run:

`self.curr.execute("set @@local.sql_mode=''")`

That should change the sql_mode for your connection. You can choose whether to include other settings such as STRICT_ALL_TABLES

Comment: I am not using this mode, please check edited question where I added the modes I am using. However, I tried it anyway with this command, but it resulted in the same error.

Comment: I've run your code against a 5.7 mysql server using mysqldb in python and it works fine for me. The error certainly seems to be at the backslash. Is the connection used by anything else that might be changing the sql mode?